# To many AsyncTask's AdWorker and AsyncTask in Threads debug mode?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im running a AsyncTask in background. I attach the AsyncTask upon orientation change. If the AsyncTask is RUNNING I let it run. If it's FINISHED is start a new AsyncTask. Now in debug mode I see the following. API level 10.

1. Is it normal to see 10 AdWorker?
2. Is it normal to see 5 AsyncTask?
3. Describe the two, purpose?
4. How do I see that just one AsyncTask is running concurrently?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 AsyncTask-  absolutely.  The AsyncTask subsystem starts up several threads it can assign AsyncTasks to, (although post 3.0 only 1 is used unless you request more via executeOnExecutor) 5 has been the default number at startup for years.  Typically only 1 is running, they execute serially on 1 thread unless told to do otherwise.  The rest are waiting for a job.

AdWorker-  that isn't part of Android.  Are you using an ad library?  If so, it looks like it either starts a lot of threads or it isn't terminating them properly.  Since you're letting the Activity terminate and restart on rotation, I suspect the ad library isn't cleaning up old threads after rotation and is letting them stick around.  Another reason why that behavior by google is idiotic and should be turned off by any app that requires threads or tasks.

Comment: Thanks! makes sense to me. Is there a way to further debug each of the 5 threads? I.e. get more info was is going on. Tools etc. or just setting breakpoints in them somehow?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in an AsyncTask it should break that specific thread (works on Eclipse, should work in Android Studio).  The ones that aren't running are just waiting on a semaphore or message queue waiting to be passed a job.  Not really much to debug.